# How to save each selected item in array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a grid with data, and when I click on a draggable icon I want to take every selected element and store it inside an array. Currently, my code works, but for some reason currently, not all selected elements are saved in the array, some get stored others not in a random way. Why is this occurring and how can I push each item once its selected in the array? Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReorderContext } from './main';
import { useDraggable, useDroppable } from '@progress/kendo-react-common';
export const DraggableRow = (props) => {
  const [dropped, setDropped] = React.useState(false);
  const [dragged, setDragged] = React.useState(false);
  const [direction, setDirection] = React.useState(null);
  const [selectedItems] = React.useState([]);
  const [initial, setInitial] = React.useState({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  });
  const { dragStart, reorder } = React.useContext(ReorderContext);
  const element = React.useRef(null);

  const handlePress = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
      element.current.style.color = 'red';
      selectedItems.push(props.dataItem);
      console.log(selectedItems);
    }
    setInitial({
      x: event.clientX - event.offsetX,
      y: event.clientY - event.offsetY,
    });
  };

  const handleDragStart = (event) => {
    if (
      !event.originalEvent.target ||
      !event.originalEvent.target.dataset.dragHandle
    ) {
      return;
    }

    setDragged(true);
    dragStart(props.dataItem);
  };

  const handleDrag = (event) => {
    if (!element.current || !dragged) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = `translateY(${
      event.clientY - initial.y + event.scrollY
    }px)`;
  };

  const handleDragEnd = () => {
    setDragged(false);
    setDropped(false);
    setInitial({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
    });
  };

  const handleRelease = () => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    element.current.style.transform = null;
  };

  const handleDragEnter = () => {
    setDropped(true);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDragOver = (event) => {
    if (!element.current) {
      return;
    }

    const rect = element.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    setDirection(
      rect.top + rect.height / 2 <= event.pageY ? 'after' : 'before'
    );
  };

  const handleDragLeave = () => {
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  const handleDrop = () => {
    reorder(props.dataItem, direction);
    setDropped(false);
    setDirection(null);
  };

  useDraggable(
    element,
    {
      onPress: handlePress,
      onDragStart: handleDragStart,
      onDrag: handleDrag,
      onDragEnd: handleDragEnd,
      onRelease: handleRelease,
    },
    {
      autoScroll: dragged,
    }
  );
  useDroppable(element, {
    onDragEnter: handleDragEnter,
    onDragOver: handleDragOver,
    onDragLeave: handleDragLeave,
    onDrop: handleDrop,
  });
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {dropped && direction === 'before' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
      <tr
        {...props.elementProps}
        ref={element}
        style={{
          backgroundColor: '#fff',
          userSelect: 'none',
          pointerEvents: dragged ? 'none' : undefined,
          opacity: dragged ? '0.8' : undefined,
        }}
      />
      {dropped && direction === 'after' && (
        <tr
          style={{
            outlineStyle: 'solid',
            outlineWidth: 1,
            outlineColor: 'red',
          }}
        />
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

and here is a runnable example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cv2hnu-euptwm?file=app/draggable-row.jsx

Comment: I couldn't understand which array? did you mean when you click on drag button(left side)  your item should store inside an array and remove from the screen?

Comment: When pressing the Ctrl key the selected item color changes to red I want once an item is selected that way to be kept in the selectedItems array

Comment: const handlePress = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey == true) {
      element.current.style.color = 'red';
      selectedItems.push(props.dataItem);
      console.log(selectedItems);
    }

Is the relevant code for that

Comment: Your selectedItems array exists at the row level, so each row is maintaining a separate selectedItems array. If you want one array that has all the selected items, you're going to need to handle that from a parent component.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that @samuei? Passing the data from the child to the parent with a function or?

Comment: You can pass a function to the child through props, yes...but you're already getting the selected item and logging it to the console in main.jsx, so why not just do it there?

Comment: That happens in the child component draggable-row.jsx component

Comment: Maybe I was seeing an outdated version, but when I opened your example, that was happening in main.jsx in the reorder method, which definitely already knows what item you've selected.

Comment: I tried to keep track of the items that are selected in the main like this: const reorder = (dataItem, direction) => {
    if (activeItem === dataItem) {
      selectedItems.push(dataItem);
      console.log(selectedItems);
    }

but I still get the same result, items are added randomly